# How to get .net session cookie in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am fairly new to C# and am trying to authenticate with a web service. The sample code that they provided shows a dummy class (DataStorageAdapter). How could I go about getting the cookie using the sessionid? Here is the example code.

```
System.Net.CookieContainer cookieContainer = DataStorageAdapter.GetCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId") ?? new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

Here is the full code below:

```
// We need a cookie that we will use in later webservice calls.
// Check if we already have a cookie saved in our system, if not, create a new one
// DataStorageAdapter is a dummy-class for this example only. You will replace this with your preferred method of storing information.
System.Net.CookieContainer cookieContainer = DataStorageAdapter.GetCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId") ?? new System.Net.CookieContainer();
// Lets initialize a Authentication Service with the cookie we have saved (or a new one if we didn't have a cookie saved)
using (Webservice.Authenticate.Authenticate authService = new Webservice.Authenticate.Authenticate { CookieContainer = cookie })
{
    // Check whether the ASP.NET_SessionId is still alive in 24SevenOffice's system. If it is not, log in again.
    if (!authService.HasSession())
    {
        // We use a credential object for logging in
        // Type is either Community or Client. A community login will always be an email address.
        Webservice.Authenticate.Credential credential = new Webservice.Authenticate.Credential
        {
            Username = "myUserName",
            Password = GetMD5("myPassword"), // See below for a MD5 encoding example method
            ApplicationId = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"), //YOUR ID HERE
            IdentityId = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") //Default is empty guid (no need to edit this)
        };
        // Do the actual log in
        String sessionId = authService.Login(credential);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
        {
            //Login returned empty string, login has failed.
            throw new Exception("Error logging into WebService, Username/Password perhaps wrong?");
        }
        //Login was successful
        //Add cookie to old domain to use the old/legacy webservices under webservices.24sevenoffice.com
        cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", sessionId) { Domain = "webservices.24sevenoffice.com" }); 
        //Save the cookie for later use so we do not need to call the Login method too often.
        DataStorageAdapter.SetCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", cookie);
    }
    //The two next lines are only needed if you wish to change from your default community ID.
    //Get a list of possible identities
    Webservice.Authenticate.Identity[] myIdentities = authService.GetIdentities();
    //Select desired identity (Alternatively, save the Identity.Id the same way you save SessionId, and use authService.SetIdentityById(Guid) )
    authService.SetIdentity(myIdentities[0]);
```

Comment: are you trying to do this in a `RequestStream`..? can you tell us what happens when you run the posted code as well as what errors you are getting if any..? please provide us with more information

Comment: That is a serious amount of comments.